# Download s3 files from specific version programatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, version-control

I made a huge mistake on all files in an S3 bucket. Hopefully, the version control was on and I have the latest versions available. However, I have A LOT of files and downloading them manually from the aws website will take so much time.

Is there a way to do it? I'm wondering if something like "Give me the version of the file if the date is different to yesterday of something like that through the command line

Thank you!!

Comment: a command like `aws s3 sync s3://bucket/prefix .` will download all latest version from an s3 path to your local machine, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @JD D, no. I want the version files before the last modification, no the actual files in the bucket